# flask with uwsgi nginx gateway timeout

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have set up a flask application to use uwsgi and nginx

I used the tutorials on the internet but I have the following issue

I have the following functions on the controller.py file

```
api_module = Blueprint('cassandra_api', __name__, url_prefix="/api")

@api_module.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return "c"
```

the above works great when trying

```
myip/api/
```

but the following doesn't work at all

```
@api_module.route("/fault_prone_snippets/", methods=['GET'])
def get_fault_prone_snippets():
    #code to connect with cassandra db and retrieve get parameters
```

When I visit

```
myip/api/faut_prone_snippets/
```

with or without get parameters, no code is executed, I don't see an error message and after the minute is over I get a gateway timeout. The problem is that when I run my flask from localhost it works great. Trying to use cassandra driver from the python console on my dev environment works too and connects with no error. How can I debug this kind of setup when it works locally but not in production?

Comment: Have you tried routing it to `"/api/fault_prone_snippets/"`? Or accesssing `"myip/faut_prone_snippets/"`?

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting a dead question here, but I'm curious and might be able to help, if needed. How long does it take you to connect to cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

As you're running behind nginx it might be that setting the `keep_alive` timeout in the `http` section of your `nginx.conf` will help. And/or `proxy_send_timeout`,
`proxy_read_timeout` parameters in the `location` section.